Make Django parse plus in URL as plus
I have a URL that contains a plus: /?a=3+4.
Is it possible to make Django (v5.1.3) to treat plus as plus, not as whitespace?

You should encode the symbol, ?a=3%2b4.

Parse it where?  Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible example

I haven't found a more specific duplicate than Plus Symbols (+) in URLs.  But essentially what you have is currently working as it should.  Don't try to change Django to handle URLs in a non-standard way.  Instead, change the URL to encode the query string values.

User enters /some-url?a=3+4. How can I get q parameter as 3+4 ? I can't encode anything.

How does the user enter it?  Directly in the url???  In a form?  Show the part of the view which gets the 3+4.

@PaulR: Do users need to be able to manually enter URLs, or can the UX of the system be modified to provide them a more controlled mechanism? If users are manually crafting URLs then it would be a good idea for the system to include some reference and/or education for users to learn about URLs.  For erroneous URLs which still get used, perhaps there's a way you can attempt to infer what the user meant when parsing the data?  Or confirm with the user if they meant to include whitespace or a + character?  This still seems less about Django and more about correcting the URL.

Exactly. I want to correct a url. Even with teaching someone can enter a url with plus.

@PaulR: Do you want to correct a URL that the user in some way provides before using that URL?  Or do you want to correct the resulting value your system reads from a URL that you otherwise have no control over?  In either case, the rules for "correcting" the string would need to be defined.  That is, you'd need some way to determine what value was intended based on what value you have.  Should a + character always be replaced with a space character?  Or is it more complex than that?  What parts of the overall process do you even control?  The question is very light on these details.

I want request.GET.get('q') output 3+4.

@PaulR, as others gave posted, you should solve this a different way...but for a possible/working solution, just eval the parameter for q. Again, this is not a good way as it appears users will be entering the values evaluated, which is possibly insecure, but it does give you what you want in string form if you encode your string in your query correctly...i.e. eval('3+4') or eval(request.GET.get('q')) equals 7. If + is an issue, although I don't see how, simply alter the value to be something else like ~ and then replace the value when parsing the GET request.
